# How to get the inserted row in Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Here is how we get the id of the added row ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed#readme)):

```
val munichId = Cities.insert {
    it[name] = "Munich"
} get Cities.id
```

What about getting the whole row? I use `map` for `select` operations but it does not work for `insert`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```kotlin
val row = Cities.insert {
    it[name] = "Munich"
}.resultedValues!!.first()
```